# If $M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & \alpha \\ 2 & -\alpha & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $Mx=b$, for some $x$,then find $x^TMx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

> If $M=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
> -1 & 0 & \alpha \\ 
> 2 & -\alpha & 0  
> \end{pmatrix} $
>   and $Mx=b$, for some $x$,then find $x^TMx$.

**My approach:**

If $Mx=b$ has a unique solution $x$ then, $\text{Rank(M)}=3$
Thus, there are three linearly independent columns in $M$.
Thus if $\alpha \neq 0$, $c_1(0,-1,2)+c_2(1, 0 ,-\alpha)+c_3(-1, \alpha ,0)=(0, 0 ,0)$ has only $c_1,c_2,c_3 =0$ as solutions.
But if $\alpha=0$, then the second and third row are linearly dependent, so the $\text{rank}(M)=2$ which is not possible.
But then I am not getting any specific value of $\alpha$ in $M$.
Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: If $\alpha = 0$, $\det M = 0$

Comment: Since $M$ is almost antisymmetric, $x^T Mx=x_1 x_3$.

Comment: It does not matter on the value of $\alpha$ actually, because $x^TMx$ is always $x_1x_3$

Comment: Where in the problem statement does it say that $Mx=b$ has a unique solution? It only says that $x$ satisfies that equation.